# how to log image info selected by the user to the log file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, logging

I am developing an iPhone application and i need to log the information about the images selected by the user to an external log file. How can this be achieved in iPhone?

I use Objective c for developing the application. I am not able to find out , which image the user has selected and get that information and write to the log file.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  This is a programming community, so code, details, specifics, etc. are necessary to truly be able to help you.  How are you getting the images, are they in a scrollview, how do you intend to log them (NSUserDefaults, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSFileHandle](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to write to a file.

```
NSFileHandle* fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"path/to/logfile"];
[fh seekToEndOfFile];
[fh writeData:[@"This is written" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fh closeFile];
```

Comment: I tried using your code.. but for some reason it's not appending to the file.. any ideas why? see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689004/how-to-access-my-iphones-log-file-on-the-iphone-itself