# how to access my iphone's log file on the iphone itself

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, shell, logging

So my app keeps on crashing and losing all the logs outputed in console. I decided to jailbreak the phone, and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3231061/766570) code to write to a file:

```
+(void)Log:(NSString *)content
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString* docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * logFile = [docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/log.txt"];                             

    NSData *dataToWrite = [content dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSFileHandle* outputFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:logFile];
    [outputFile seekToEndOfFile];
    [outputFile writeData:dataToWrite];    
    [outputFile closeFile];
}
```

if I put a break point, the value of *outputFile* looks like this: 
/var/mobile/Applications/B8AB0D75-7FBE-4C5B-8D48-2ABCE9C7564D/Documents/log.txt

I installed vim on my phone via cydia, and there is no log.txt in the said directory! (I've SSH'd into my iPhone using [iphone tunnel](http://code.google.com/p/iphonetunnel-mac/) as root SSH. On another attempt, I manually created the log.txt using vim and ran the code again.. still nothing gets appended to the file.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out to be a writing permission to the file.. so i just chmod'ed it and it works fine.. D'OH!